# JavaFX UI creation & Progress bar Update

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, task, runnable

I have a rather tricky question here .

**What I have :**

I am currently making a JavaFX application that renders a graph ( with lots of nodes and edges ) on the screen . I am able to construct the graph using the Graphiz library and it shows fine on my screen . But the graph rendering can take time bex my graph can contain >1000+ nodes and I drawing them on the screen is slow . Here is my code to do that

```
protected synchronized void layoutWithGraphviz() {
    if (listener == null)
        listener = new LayoutResultListener();
    Utils.CreateGraphLayout(this,
            listener);
}
```

Now my `LayoutResultListener()` is a listener that ensures that the vertex on view dont overlap each other / look nice and hence I redraw the graph if they dont . This all works perfectly .

**What I need :**

I want a progress bar to show my overall progress . Now since I am unsure how many times my LayoutResultLisener() will be called so i am OK with an indeterminate progress bar . However the tricky part is I cant delegate the UI creation part to a background thread as JavaFX doesnt allow this . I see it documented here as well [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)

So i dont know what to do I cannot delegrate UI creation to background thread . So how do i show a progress bar ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your UI creation code inside :

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //your JAVAFX UI codes
    }

});
```